# How to use Piped IO Streams

Tags: java, io

From the documentation for [`PipedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and [`PipedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html),
the former forms the receiving end of a communication pipe and the latter is the sending end. This forms a structure like this:
A -> `PipedInputStream` -> `PipedOutputStream` -> B
My question is how do I specify what A and B are. I would like A to be the standard input stream `System.in` and B to be a `FileOutputStream`.
Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the Piped Stream objects offer a way to connect an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`. Yet I don't see any methods for connecting a `PipedInputStream` to anything other than a `PipedOutputStream`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You linked to the javadoc of [`PipedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html), but it seems like you didn't read it.

> A piped output stream can be connected to a piped input stream to create a communications pipe. The **piped output stream is the sending end** of the pipe. Typically, data is **written to a `PipedOutputStream` object by one thread** and data is **read from the connected `PipedInputStream` by some other thread**.

So, the data flows in the opposite direction from what the question shows:

```
Thread A  →  PipedOutputStream  →  PipedInputStream  →  Thread B
```

As you can see, I also clarified it by showing that **`A` and `B` are *threads*, i.e. code, not other streams**.

---

> Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the Piped Stream objects offer a way to connect an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`.

As you can see from the description above, you're wrong about that. Piped Stream objects offer a way for a thread to send data to another thread using Stream I/O calls.

They are called "piped" because it works similar to how one program can write to stdout, and another program can read from stdin, and you can then connect the two using a `|` pipe, e.g. `foo.exe | bar.exe` will pipe the output from the `foo` program as input to the `bar` program.

That's just between *processes*, while the Piped Streams are between *threads*.

---

> I would like `A` to be the standard input stream `System.in` and `B` to be a `FileOutputStream`.

If you want to copy from `System.in` to a file, you can do any of the following:

```java
// Using newer NIO.2 API (Java 7+)
Files.copy(System.in, Paths.get(filename), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

```java
// Using old File I/O API with transferTo (Java 9+)
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename))) {
    System.in.transferTo(out);
}
```

```java
// Using old File I/O API with try-with-resources (Java 7+)
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename))) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    for (int len; (len = System.in.read(buf)) > 0; )
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

```java
// Using old File I/O API (any Java version)
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
try {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    for (int len; (len = System.in.read(buf)) > 0; )
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: After calling the `InputStream.transferTo()` is possible to undo the effect of this method later on.

Comment: @febot The undo of creating a file is deleting it, so .... yeah!?

Comment: That is not what I meant. I was asking if there was a way to stop `System.in` from transferring its data to a specified `OutputStream`. After calling `System.in.transferTo(...)`, is there a way to return `System.in` to the state it was in, before calling the `transferTo()` method.

Comment: @febot No, you'd have to write your own copy loop, like shown in answer, then look for some end-of-data marker in the data being copied.

Answer (score 5):

First of all the direction of communication is
*A* -> `PipedOutputStream` -> `PipedInputStream` -> *B*.

It is not possible to set *A* or *B* to some specific streams.
*A* simply represents a thread that calls the `write()` method of `PipedOutputStream` to submit some data, which is then transferred to the `PipedInputStream` from which another thread *B* can read it using the `read()` method.

Answer (score 4):

`PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` are used to create a pipe between two threads.

Usually you do something like:

- Create a `PipedOutputStream` and a `PipedInputStream` and connect them
- Start a thread that writes to `PipedOutputStream`
- Start a thread that reads from `PipedInputStream`